# Why is $_POST['submit'] NULL here?

Tags: php, html, ajax, null, form-submit

This `$_POST['submit']` is driving me crazy. I don't see any reason why its value is NULL.

This is my PHP code:

```
if(isset($_POST['username'])  && isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['email2']) && isset($_POST['password']) 
&& isset($_POST['firstname']) && isset($_POST['surname']) && isset($_POST['gender']) && isset($_POST['day'])
&& isset($_POST['month'])  && isset($_POST['year']) ) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $email2 = $_POST['email2'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $gender = $_POST['gender'];
    $day = $_POST['day'];
    $month = $_POST['month'];
    $year = $_POST['year'];

    $date = $year."-".$month."-".$day;

    $hashed_password = hashMe($password,$salt);


    if (!preg_match("/^[a-z](?=[\w.]{3,19}$)\w*\.?\w*$/i", $username)) {

        echo "invalid username";
    }
    if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        echo "Invalid email.";
    }
    if ($email !== $email2) {

        echo "Emails are not matching.";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^([^\s])[a-zA-Z]*$/i", $firstname)) {

        echo "Invalid first name.";
    }
    if (!preg_match("/^([^\s])[a-zA-Z]*$/i", $surname)) {

        echo "Invalid last name.";
    }
    if($day === "Day" || $month === "Month" || $year === "Year") {

        echo "Choose a date.";

    }
    if($gender === "Your gender:") {

        echo "choose a gender.";
    }
    else if(array_key_exists('submit', $_POST))
    {
        $mysqli = new mysqli('blaa', 'blablaa', 'blabla', 'cucumber');

        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            echo "Connection Failed: " . mysqli_connect_errno();
            exit();
        }

        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO USERS (USER_USERNAME, USER_EMAIL, USER_GENDER, USER_FIRSTNAME, USER_LASTNAME,         USER_BIRTHDAY, USER_PASSWORD, USER_SALT) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
        $stmt->bind_param('ssssssss',$username,$email,$gender,$firstname,$surname,$date,$hashed_password,$salt);
        $stmt->execute();

        echo "everything successfully inserted into the database \n";



    }
    else{
        var_dump($_POST['submit']);
        echo "something went wrong!"; 
    }
}
```

And this is my button code:

```
<input class="btn btn-large btn-success" id="register-button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Registreer" onclick="handlePost()"/>
```

Useful to know maybe: I've tried reading all log files, nothing there. All other values are being sent to the server nicely, so there's no problem with the rest of the form. `handlePost()`makes an Ajax call to the server. using `var_dump($_POST)`I'm getting everything except submit. And `var_dump($_POST['submit'])` gives me NULL.

UPDATE: `handlePost()`:

```
function handlePost() {  

 var username = $('#username').val();  
 var email = $('#email').val();  
 var email2 = $('#email2').val(); 
 var password = $('#password').val();   
 var firstname = $('#firstname').val();
 var surname = $('#surname').val();
 var gender = $('#gender').val();
 var day = $('#day').val();
 var month = convertMonth($('#month').val())
 console.log(month);
 var year = $('#year').val();

 $.ajax({  
   type: "POST",  
   url: "handleRegister.php",  
   data: "username="+username+"&email="+email+"&email2="+email2+"&password="+password+"&firstname="
   +firstname+"&surname="+surname+"&gender="+gender+"&day="+day+"&month="+month+"&year="+year,  
   success: function(resp){  
     // we have the response  
     //alert("Server said:\n '" + resp + "'");  

     console.log("Server said:\n '" + resp + "'");

   },  
   error: function(e){  
     //alert('Error: ' + e);  
     console.log("Server said:\n '" + e + "'");
   }  
 });  
}
```

I'm not using `<form>`, so I guess I also have to send `'submit'` ?

Comment: What if you take `firebug` and see what actually has been sent? Most likely it just hasn't been passed at all thus the problem is on the client, not with php

Comment: Might also help to see handlePost().

Comment: We cannot see the rest of the `<form>`. Is the submit button inside the `<form>`?

Comment: Just check your input button located inside the `<form>` or please put your HTML code as well.

Comment: Do you have multiple submit buttons with different values?  Is that why you need to know the value of `$_POST['submit']`?

Comment: I'm using chrome and var_dump($_POST) contains everything. So everything in the if-statement at the top of the code passes. Only $_POST['submit'] is empty.

Comment: Then it's obviously not being sent to the server.  Show us your handlePost() code. You're liking building your data for your AJAX request without including the submit stuff.

Comment: `isset()` accepts multiple parameters. You can simplify to `isset($_POST['key1'], $_POST['key2'], ...)`

Comment: @Corbin I updated my question with the rest of the code.

Comment: Your data string does not contain the submit stuff, so you need to add it.  Also, as long as the fields are all in the form, you might be able to simplify your code with $("#form").serialize().

Comment: @SenorAmor, I don't care about the value of that. But there are some stuff I want to do before actually clicking the button (live validation) and then I want to actually register after clicking on the button. So I guess $_POST['submit'] must no be null then?

Comment: @Corbin , how do I do that? "&submit="+submit ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `data` string does not contain the submit field.  If you add it, it should solve your problem.

`var sbmt = $('#register-button').val();`

and

`data: "username="+username+"&email="+email+"&email2="+email2+"&password="+password+"&firstname="
   +firstname+"&surname="+surname+"&gender="+gender+"&day="+day+"&month="+month+"&year="+year+"&submit="+sbmt`

Answer (score 1):

How does `handlePost()` make the AJAX call?

I'm of the impression that the submit button value will only be included in the POST data if the event to submit the form comes from the button itself (which is why when you have numerous submit buttons, only the one that was clicked is included in the data).

**Edit:**

The `data` property in your `$.ajax` call must contain everything you want to send to the server; it won't automatically include form values you haven't specified.

Doing an AJAX call is not the same as submitting your form normally, regardless of how it is triggered.

Comment: handlePost() is actually triggered with this button, so it must be sent to handleRegister.php right?